# How to place a text between two images in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create layout where I have two images at left and at right and text in center.

I have tried to do it with relative layout but unfortunetly it was unsuccessfully. Could anybody provide me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/img1"
        android:text="I'm between!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you don't need more things on your view, you could want to use `LinearLayout` instead, since it's more easier to implement. In that case, you just have to play with the `layout_weight` attribute.

[image]

Comment: I have done it exectly in the same way but it won't work, the text is not between two images. Any alternativities? I understand that I can use LinearLayout but I want to figure out why it doesn't works with RelativeLayout.

Comment: Maybe you are doing it the wrong way. I posted an image of how it looks in my phone, using the code I provided.

Comment: Hm, thanks for your response, I will try to figure out what is wrong.. But it looks like there is no differences.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works for me to, I have found minor differences such as android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead of fixed size of images and also I have not specified android:layout_alignTop="@id/img1". One more difference is that I am usnig predefined styles. Maybe the reason is there but I am not sure. Many thanks to you!