# How to center text between two images in Android

Tags: android, image, text, center, alignment

I need to center a small amount of text between two images. This post nearly achieves what I want, however the text is left aligned and not centered between the two images.

[How to place a text between two images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079723/how-to-place-a-text-between-two-images-in-android/4079756#4079756)

I've tried using android:layout_centerInParent, but the text got displayed over the images instead of wrapping between them.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use linearlayout with orientation is horizontal.Besides TextView should be set layout_weight = "1",

Comment: This works and I like it as it is a much simpler implementation - thanks a mil.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:gravity="center" or android:layout_gravity="center".